# Best practise to filter content based on the userid in Django?

Tags: django, django-views

I'm creating a Django based movie collection that stores DVDs/BDs to a database. Application saves these movies to an Archive. A user can have one archive but archive can be used by multiple people (a family members, for example, can share same archive). And same with Django models:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    archive = models.ForeignKey(Archive, blank=True, null=True)

class Archive(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Movie(models.Model):
    archive = models.ForeignKey(Archive)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
```

What is the best practice to make sure, that the user can see only movies and other information that belongs to the user's archive?

Of course filter() would do the job, but is there a way to do filtering so that it is done only once for all views? With a middleware? Or a decorator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your URL-style is to have just something like `/movies/some-movie/`, @jknupp's answer is probably your best bet, but if you're doing something more like `/user/some-user/movies/some-movie/`. It's the view's responsibility to ensure that only movies belonging to the user are shown.

In either case, it's pretty much still the view's responsibility, in some form or another. This is the natural division of the MVC design pattern (which Django does utilize, albeit loosely). The model doesn't know, nor should it know, anything about the user. It's purpose is to simply allow storage and retrieval of data in every scenario. The view, however, does know about users because it's handling the request and therefore the session, so any processing that's session-specific (such as permissions and authentication) belong there.

However, that's not to say you can't still off-load work to the model. My suggestion would be to create a custom manager method that filters items for a particular user, which you can then use in your view. For example:

```
class MovieQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def allowed_for_user(self, user):
        return self.filter(archive__user=user)

class MovieManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def get_query_set(self):
        return MovieQuerySet(self.model)

    def allowed_for_user(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get_query_set().allowed_for_user(*args, **kwargs)

class Movie(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = MovieManager()
```

Granted, that manager method is rather simplistic, but it still requires knowledge that you must query the user through the movie's archive foreign key, and that type of knowledge is the purview of the model/manager. Then in your view, you'd just have to do:

```
movies = Movie.objects.allowed_for_user(request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [permission-required decorator.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#the-permission-required-decorator) It's likely exactly what you need.